# Geodjango application getting error while installing on RHEL6

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, rhel6

I am trying to install a geo-django application in RHEL 6.5 machine. The application was working fine in Ubuntu 12.04 (python 2.7, django 1.4, mapnik, tilecache & postgis(9.1) enabled postgresql 9.1)   .  But when I installed the same in RHEL 6.5  , postgis query using geodjango API is not working. The query is

```
pt1 = MyModel.objects.filter(thegeom__dwithin=(the_geom, 250)).distance(the_geom).order_by('distance')
```

where "the_geom" is the geometry value from another table.

While executing this query I am getting error

***'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'***

The traceback error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/query.py", line 100, in distance
    return self._distance_attribute('distance', geom, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/query.py", line 582, in _distance_attribute
    geodetic = geo_field.geodetic(connection)
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 131, in geodetic
    return self.units_name(connection) in self.geodetic_units
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 122, in units_name
    self._get_srid_info(connection)
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 108, in _get_srid_info
    self._units, self._units_name, self._spheroid = get_srid_info(self.srid, connection)
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 35, in get_srid_info
    units, units_name = sr.units
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py", line 280, in units
    return (self.linear_units, self.linear_name)
  File "/opt/MyApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base.py", line 252, in linear_units
    return m.group('unit')
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Please post more of the traceback, that error by itself explains very little.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I have added the whole traceback error